# How to use shiny.setInputValue within a module?

Tags: javascript, shiny, shinyjs, shinymodules

I am using the `shinyjs::runjs("Shiny.setInputValue(...))` command to get the innerText value of the 'calendar_renderRange' span of the toastui calendar widget. The command is working in a non modularized app context but not in a modularized app context. See the code below.

**App without a module:**

```
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)


ui <- basicPage(
  useShinyjs(),  
  dateRangeInput(
    "calendar_daterange",
    label = "Data Range",
    start = lubridate::today(),
    end = lubridate::today() %m+% period("1 month"),
    startview = "year"
  ),
  toastui::calendarOutput("calendar"),
  textOutput("tag")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$calendar <- toastui::renderCalendar(toastui::calendar(view = 'month',
                                                               navigation = TRUE))
  
  observeEvent(c(input[["calendar_renderRange"]], input[["calendar_prev"]], input[["calendar_next"]], input[["calendar_daterange"]]),{
    shinyjs::runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('calendar_renderRange', calendar_renderRange.innerText);")
  })
  
  output$tag <- renderPrint({
    req(input[["calendar_renderRange"]])
    print(input$calendar_renderRange)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Same App with a module:**

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyjs)

tableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    dateRangeInput(
      ns("calendar_daterange"),
      label = "Data Range",
      start = lubridate::today(),
      end = lubridate::today() %m+% period("1 month"),
      startview = "year"
    ),
    toastui::calendarOutput(ns("calendar")),
    textOutput(ns("tag2"))
  )
}

tableServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
  
    output$calendar <- toastui::renderCalendar(toastui::calendar(view = 'month',
                                                                 navigation = TRUE))
    
    observeEvent(c(input[["calendar_renderRange"]], input[["table1-calendar_prev"]], input[["table1-calendar_next"]], input[["calendar_daterange"]]),{
      print('okkk')
      shinyjs::runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('calendar_renderRange', table1-calendar_renderRange.innerText);")
    })

    output$tag2 <- renderPrint({
      print(input[['calendar_renderRange']])
    })
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tableUI("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  tableServer("table1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here are the solutions I've tried but none are working:

`shinyjs::runjs(sprintf('Shiny.setInputValue("%s", table1-calendar_renderRange.innerText);', session$ns("calendar_renderRange")))`

`shinyjs::runjs(sprintf('Shiny.setInputValue("%s", calendar_renderRange.innerText);', session$ns("calendar_renderRange")))`

`JS(sprintf('Shiny.setInputValue("%s", calendar_renderRange.innerText);', session$ns("calendar_renderRange")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the JS `getElementById` function to get the input ID.
Here is a way of how you could define the shiny module server.

Reference:
*To reference an input id via setInputValue in a modular app that uses namespaces, simply add the namespace id in front of the input id, separated by a dash*: [Shiny.setInputValue in modular app with namespaces](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-setinputvalue-in-modular-app-with-namespaces/23263)

```
moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$calendar <- toastui::renderCalendar(toastui::calendar(view = 'month',
                                                                 navigation = TRUE))
    
    observeEvent(c(input[["Date_du_calendrier"]], input[["calendar_prev"]], input[["calendar_next"]]),{
      print('osbv')
      shinyjs::runjs(
        paste0(
          "Shiny.setInputValue('",id,"-Date_du_calendrier', document.getElementById('",id,"-calendar_renderRange').innerText);"
        )
      )
    })
    
    output$tag2 <- renderPrint({
      print(input[["Date_du_calendrier"]])
    })
  }
```